# Converting a date string to date format then do subtraction

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am given two dates as strings below, and I want to subtract them to get the number 16 as my output. I tried converting them to date format first and then doing the math, but it didn't work.

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = '2021-05-27'
prev_date_string = '2021-05-11'
a = datetime.strptime(date_string '%y/%m/%d')
b = datetime.strptime(prev_date_string '%y/%m/%d')
c = a - b
print (c)
```

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean?

Comment: Why do you try to use a date format string containing forward slashes when your date strings are formatted with hyphens?

Comment: Isn't there also a `,` missing between `strptime`'s arguments?

Comment: Besides, you could use [fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with the `strptime` calls. First, they are missing commas (`,`) between the two arguments. Second, the format string you use must match the format of the dates you have.

Also, note the result of subtracting two `datetime` objects is a [`timedelta` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects). If you just want to print out the number 16, you'll need to extract the `days` property of the result:

```py
a = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d')
b = datetime.strptime(prev_date_string, '%Y-%m-%d')

c = a-b

print (c.days)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer for this problem.

```
from datetime import date

a = date(2021, 5, 11)
b = date(2021, 5, 27)
c = b - a
print(c.days)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.